# How can i extract one value from this .xml to a string? c#

Tags: c#, xml, text-extraction, information-extraction

The xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<MPL Version="2.0" Title="JRSidecar" PathSeparator="\">
<Item>
<Field Name="Filename">F:\FILMS\2 Guns.mkv</Field>
<Field Name="Rating">3</Field>
<Field Name="Genre">ACTION</Field>
</Item>
</MPL>
```

i start :

```
var document = XDocument.Load(@"F:\test\2 Guns.xml");
```

after i try :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();ds.ReadXml(@"F:\test\2 Guns.xml");
string note = ds.Tables["ITEM"].Rows[0][1].ToString();
var rating = document.Descendants("Rating").Select(element => element.Value);
```

i miss something...  thanks for your help.
After i will put that different values ( filename, rating, genre.. ) in a dataGridView1 (i know how).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string filePath = @"e:\Temp\Stegau.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

    string Filename = xdoc.Descendants("Field").Where(v => v.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "Filename").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
    string Rating = xdoc.Descendants("Field").Where(v => v.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "Rating").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
    string Genre = xdoc.Descendants("Field").Where(v => v.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "Genre").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

    Console.WriteLine("Filename='{0}', Rating='{1}', Genre='{2}'",
        Filename, Rating, Genre);
}
```

**Output**

Filename='F:\FILMS\2 Guns.mkv', Rating='3', Genre='ACTION'

Comment: Thank you! It works! I was looking for that all the day... I learn a lot here.